# Is Meta Stack Overflow broken?

Tags: support, mobile-web

**Update: I browse this site again in incognito mode, everything seems normal. Not sure whether is this still a valid case**

I visit Meta SO and I am surprised to find that there are a lot of changes to the UI, especially the homepage:

[image: Meta SO UI]

But this is not the Meta SO that I am used to. The one that I am used to looks just like the main site, with less contrast in colors:

[image: SO UI]

And even the meta.superuser.com looks the same.
[image: Meta SU UI]

The functionality of this website is so broken that I can't even upload image.

This looks to me like a mobile website, but I am using a laptop to access it.

Is it a valid change, or is it something broken?

Comment: Can you give us your browser details and platform you're using? You're getting the mobile theme and I have no idea why.

Comment: @Tim Post, I open the link in incognito Google Chrome, and now the problem is gone.

Comment: I press CTRL+F5 to force refresh my browser, the same problem occurs in normal mode

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is always broken. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably accidentally clicked on the 'mobile' link at the bottom of the page (when the website is in 'Normal' mode).

[image]

The solution is quite simple: on the Mobile version of the website, there is a link 'full site':

[image]

This setting is stored in the `theme` cookie – `0` is normal, `2` is mobile. That's why your Incognito mode still shows a normal Meta Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Set your cookie value to 1 to see how deep the rabbit hole goes.

Comment: @null nothing happens for me (Firefox on Mac) ...

Comment: Would be a nice Easter egg though =)

Comment: Yup, that's the problem